# rtf2latex2e convert ÷ symbol to Ã· in windows

Tags: equations, symbols

I am new to TEx and LaTex formats. i am using rtf2latex23 in window 8.1. from yesterday (11-sep-2014) only i am using this application. while converting the "RTF" file i found that The "÷" symbol is converted to "Ã·" kindly help

```
%&pdfLaTeX % !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode 
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{ifxetex} 
\ifxetex 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{STIXGeneral} 
\else 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\fi 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace{5mm}} 
\begin{document}
```

Comment: accented A usually indicates the file is in utf-8 encoding but being mis-read as latin1, try adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` if that does not work make a small complete document that you can post into ypur question that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Best to put code in the question as you can not format it in comments. Please complete the document with an example of "÷" that typesets incorrectly so we can see how it was converted

Comment: Q.1) ?÷0.5×24=5652   "This is the original format from windows rtf" when i use rtf2latex2e the result is "Q.1) ?Ã·0.5\ensuremath{\times}24=5652"

Comment: If you have em-dashes, or accents (`—`, `á`), it also gets it wrong sometimes, puting the dashes in a different paragraph where they belong, and changing many accented words to a `Á` (e.g., `cábala` to `cÁbala`) and many weird things. I think it doesn't work well with UTF8.

Answer (score 2):

`Ã·` is

U+00c3 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE
  U+00b7 MIDDLE DOT

the two bytes C3 B7 if viewed as latin 1 are A-tilde and middle dot, but if they are read as UTF-8 they are the single character `÷`

so it looks like your file has been "double encoded" to UTF-8 twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. what i have to do for not double encoding..

Comment: @MadhanSeeman I have no idea:-) impossible to tell from here whether it's a bug in the convertor or in the way you are saving the input or output